# How to "mount" data lake gen 1 without databricks

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, azure-data-lake

We have pyspark codes that we want to run in kubernetes. It should pick up data from a data lake gen 1 storage. Now, I understand that in Databricks to be able to access files in data lake, it should be mounted first. I want to ask if: a.) it is possible b.) what is the approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do it is by following [this documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure-datalake/index.html) from Apache Hadoop. Make sure you download the correct JARs into your classpath.

You will need to set the various parameters in the hadoop core-site.xml file, and example of which is as follows, using ClientCredential and OAuth2 (I replaced private info with xxxx):

```
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type</name>
      <value>ClientCredential</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>fs.adl.oauth2.refresh.url</name>
      <value>https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/token</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>fs.adl.oauth2.client.id</name>
      <value>xxxx</value>
  </property>

  <property>
      <name>fs.adl.oauth2.credential</name>
      <value>xxxx</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```